# Python3 - CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SQL line given a sample machine name

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a automated scripting assignment from school... I'm trying to create a table if it does not exists. But I want the table to have the hostname from the machine (it's working on virtual machine's). I have tried searching on the magical interwebs. But I can't find a clear answer to it.

Is it possible to add a hostname like this?

```
#!/bin/python3
import psutil
import socket
import mysql.connector




machine = socket.gethostname()
memory = psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
disk = psutil.disk_usage('/').percent
cpu = psutil.cpu_percent()
#print (machine, memory, disk, cpu)

def create_table():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.0.2',
                                             database='gegevens',
                                             user='db_user',
                                             password='Welkom01')
        if connection.is_connected():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ machine("virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);")
            cursor.execute(sql)
            connection.commit()

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")


create_table()
```

Or do you guys suggest I'm doing it differently. Because when i'm trying to run it like this, i'm getting a TypeError;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./agent.py", line 36, in <module>
    create_table()
  File "./agent.py", line 23, in create_table
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ machine("virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

With many to quamrana and S3DEV I have figured out how to make it done... I have changed line 23:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ machine("virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);")
```

into:

```
sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {machine} (virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255))"
```

With this is it working.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: done @quamrana there is a screenshot called: full traceback error

Comment: Really, You know how to paste an *image* to imgur and paste a link into your question, but not just copy and paste the text of the error?

Comment: I have changed it :3

Comment: Ok, what does `machine("virt ... ")` mean? `machine` is a string.

Comment: It's this line: `machine("virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);")`.  `machine` is a string, presumably the hostname. However it's being called line a function.  Change to `machine + "virtual ..."`.  Or, better yet - look up string formatting, specifically **f-strings**.

Comment: So how can I work around this? As I want the table to have the name of the host? But it should only create the table if it does not exists?

Comment: This is a very simple string formatting issue.  [Have a look here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings) for a bit of guidance.

Comment: Please update your question with an example `CREATE TABLE` SQL line given a sample machine name.

Comment: @S3DEV I have found it! Thank you very much:

           ``` 
sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {machine} (virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255))"
```

Comment: *I want the table to have the hostname from the machine* ... this may not be the best table design as it sounds like you will create a *new* table for a *different* hostname. Identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) in relational database should not themselves contain data elements. Consider a **single** `machine` table with `hostname` as a column and store ALL hostname data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just the sql string wrong. You are trying to add 3 strings together but are mixing up the syntax, here are a few options with the correct syntax:

```py
# option 1
sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {machine} (virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255)(;"
# option 2
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255));".format(
   table_name=machine
)
```

Basically 'machine' in your code is a string and is the sql block you have there, we want this string to be 'injected' into our string.

The way to do this in python is using string format/formatted string or even just plain concatetation (I prefer the first two options for you use-case as they are a bit more clear)

See this article for more information: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the way you try to format your sql query.
Please change the below line:

```py
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ machine("virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);")
```

To a format string like this:

```py
sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {machine} (virtual_mem varchar(255), disk_usage varchar(255),cpu_usage varchar (255);"
```

It would be even better if you checked out the formatting options offered by the mysql connector so the query substitution would be executed by the connector engine, which most probably guards against SQL injection issues.